Got multiple values for argument 'intermediate_steps' when accessing data in dataframe
I have written a simple chatbot to query data in dataframe using LangChain but I am getting an error

Agent.plan() got multiple values for argument 'intermediate_steps'

My original problem was the execution time was too short. Thus added agent_executor to increase max_execution_time=30. Now a new issue that I haven't been able to solve. Sharing my code below.
Can someone help?
import urllib3
import json
import pandas as pd
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI, OpenAI
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain_experimental.tools import PythonREPLTool
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool, AgentExecutor

load_dotenv()

url = f"https://catalogue.data.govt.nz/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=f65dfeb4-94be-4879-957c-e081d9570216&limit=1"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request("GET", url)

response = json.loads(response.data.decode("utf-8"))

total_records = response["result"]["total"]

# get all records until total_records
records = []
limit = 1000
offset = 0
while offset < total_records:
    url = f"https://catalogue.data.govt.nz/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=f65dfeb4-94be-4879-957c-e081d9570216&limit={limit}&offset={offset}"
    response = http.request("GET", url)
    response = json.loads(response.data.decode("utf-8"))
    records.extend(response["result"]["records"])
    offset += limit

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
# Set the first row as the column names
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df_columns = df.columns.tolist()

python = PythonREPLTool(locals={"df": df})

tools = [
    Tool(
        "ECE data",
        func=python.run,
        description=f"When answering questions Run python pandas operations on 'df; to help you get the right answers. 'df' has the following columns: {df_columns}. Load the dataframe 'df' to see the data.",
    )
]

llm = ChatOpenAI()
agent = initialize_agent(
    tools=tools, agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, llm=llm
)


agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
    agent=agent,
    tools=tools,
    verbose=True,
    max_execution_time=30,
    return_intermediate_steps=False,
)
print(agent_executor.invoke({"input": "List 5 organisations in Auckland"}))


Fixed the issue by using langchain_experimental and importing create_pandas_dataframe_agent. Downside, I need to set allow_dangerous_code=True
